# How can QGIS 3.X create atlas by a group field?

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, atlas, grouping

I have a line layer with 8 features and a field TYPE (5 features is type_A and 5 features is type_B). I want to create a atlas which output is two single image (one is grouped by typ_A with 5 features, other is grouped by type_B with 3 features) by using Rule-based Symbology to control the features showing or not. But it seems the atlas create 8 single images not what I want. So is there a way to achieve my goal?I have more than 100 features group by more than 10 different types.[image: 8 features group by 2 types]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the solution to my qestion myself.In my example what I need to do is using Delete duplicates by attribute in my testA layer to generate a new layer with only two features(one is type_A,another is type_B).Next I set the coverage layer is the new layer with only two features and hidden it in the Atlas configuration .My qgis version is 3.6.3.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for a similar solution as you described! I guess it is not possible... yet! However, instead of using "duplicates by attributes" I used the "Dissolve" tool to merge features by attribute. And then I used the new layer as a hidden layer as you did.